# Why would I be returning error codes using Javascript calls to my basic web service?

Tags: javascript, web-services, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I am hosting an ASP.NET web application in IIS and have added a TestWebService.asmx file to support some API calls.   This web service was based on a web service that has been working using SOAP for several years.   I am having problems calling this new test web application method from Javascript however.    Ultimately I want to support invoking the web method using JSON and XML formats.

SOAP interfaces to my web services successfully invoke the web method and return successfully.

I have created a Test web method in TestWebService to get the most basic scenario to work for me.   I appear to be missing something fundamental.   Ultimately I want to return JSON objects from my more complex web methods.

What appears to work.

1. I can invoke Test by formatting the url with parameters on the url.
2. My web method experiences no errors.
3. I can perform back end processing and even format a return JSON string in more complex methods.

What does not work.

1. My Javascript calls never report a successful response to my web methods using the XMLHttpRequest class or the .AJAX method.

My web service TestWebService.cs - ScriptService is set and ScriptMethod is set on the Test method

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for TestWebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://Test.org/TestWebService")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// Allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class TestWebService : WebService
{
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public void Test(string string1)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("{'success':'true'}");
    }
}
```

In my TestWebPage.html, using XMLHttpRequest.

```
 function Test()
  {
      alert("In Test 1");
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          alert("In callback 1, readState=" + this.readState + ", status=" + this.status + ", response=" + xhttp.responseText);
          if (this.readState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              alert("Test success");
          }
      };
      var address = "http://localhost/TestWebService/TestWebService.asmx/Test?string1=teststring";
      xhttp.open("GET", address, true);
      xhttp.send();
  }
```

AJAX Version of Test()

```
function Test()
 {
    var test = "teststring";
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://localhost/TestWebService/TestWebService.asmx/Test",
           data: {string1: test},
           dataType: "html",
           contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
           }).done(function(data) {
              alert("Test success");
          }).fail(function (jgXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
           {
             alert("Test failed - " + jgXHR.responseText + " ,status =" + textStatus + " ,err= " + errorThrown);
           });
  }
```

Ultimately I want to receive the "Test success" alert message from my read callbacks.   In the web service I see that the status code is set to 200.    With the XMLHttpRequest call, I only see response code values of 0.   With the AJAX call, I see an Undefined status text value. (Not helpful)

I used the urlencoded type for contentType since I was able to get this to call the web method.

I have been unable to get my web service to response when I use AJAX with the following settings.

```
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

It appears that I need to change a setting on my web server to receive JSON requests.

However, when I set the dataType to be jsonp, I do receive the request in my web service.  The problem for JSONP is that my web service is not invoking the callback method even if specified by jsonCallack.    My investigation has indicated that I may need to add a JsonPFormatter which would invoke the callback.   I attempted to add the formatter in Application_Start for my web service and this did not help however.

Any input to lead me to a successful result from my Javascript calls is appreciated.

Comment: In your "`ajax`" part data should be `data: 'string1='+test`

Comment: Thanks, I am able to receive the values on my web service using the data: {string1: test} or data: 'string1=' + test

Comment: Which version of jQuery? Use 'type' if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0, otherwise, 'method'. For the url don't use the full protocol just start with root / and go the method.